# How do javascript timeouts work in the execution stack?

Tags: javascript, timeout, ecmascript-5

During a test this question appeared. Here is a photo taken by a classmate.

Keep in mind, I chose  "line 8" as my answers, despite having a feeling it calls back the function again.

Here is an image of the question.

[image]

now there was some debate amongst a few different developers I asked as to what the correct answer is.

My Debugger shows that the next line executed is 8, which makes since because I thought JS executes line by line.

can someone explain to me why "Line 8" is incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is correct (line 8).

Comment: Hi there, this is one of my favorite videos in the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=635s its from jsconf.

Comment: @Pointy I have many telling me its incorrect. Can you explain?

Comment: Why not simply run the code in your browser? The call to `setTimeOut()` returns immediately; the callback function won't run until 2 seconds later.

Comment: Make sure the people who are telling you the wrong answer (line 4) are aware that `setTimeout()` is invoked with a **string** containing the callback code. Generally that would be considered bad practice; it should be `setTimeout(countIt, 2000)`, but it isn't.

Comment: The example seems to be full of bad practices ...

Comment: That is what I thought, which is why I spent most of my test time looking at this. Hello again Teemu

Comment: @Pointy so what you are saying is that when setTimeout is called, it isn't actually calling line 4 next because there is a timeout, and during those 2 seconds line 8 is called, and then after 2 seconds, the function is run. So it runs line 7, which doesn't call line 4 for 2 seconds, and then move onto line 8?

So 8 is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, 8 is the correct answer. If you replace the `document.write()` calls (another bad practice) with `console.log()` you can see it for yourself right there in your browser console.

Comment: Also whoever made up the test misspelled `setTimeout()` (it's lower-case "out")

Comment: So, all the alternatives are incorrect, beacuse the test breaks to reference error.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean all the alternatives? Are you saying 8 is the only correct answer ( lets pretend for a second there aren't any typos in his test example lol ).

Comment: As it was when you saw it, there was that typo, hence the reference error, and even line 8 would have never been executed. I drew my first comment off, I missed, that the function call was wrapped in the quotes. But if it wasn't, still the line 8 would've been the correct answer (without the typo), because the function would had been executed before the line 7 was finished.

Comment: @Teemu now I am confused. 8 is the correct answer, but you say "because the function would had been executed before the line 7 was finished".

Comment: @MarioPerez Thank you very much for this link. We are enjoying it

Comment: That was just a speculation, if the timer had set like `setTimeout(countIt(), 2000)`. In that case `countIt` would had been executed before the line 7 was finished  (because arguments must be evaluated before the function can be run), hence the next line executed immediately after the line 7 would had been the line 8.